# Toshiba satellite L640 laptop issues with battery and OS

Tags: battery

In my laptop Toshiba satellite L640, there are 2 issues
1] when I press on Power button it does not start OS I have to press any keys to start the OS.
2] When the battery is inserted in its slot and charger is connected, the battery does not charge in fact the status doesn not even change to Plugged in. But, when I remove the battery and turn the laptop on it works fine.

Can anyone please help me in these issues ?

Answer (score 0):

the first issue,you can fix in the BIOS, you can set your PC to turn on by pressing any key on the keyboard, you have to remove this configuration and you're done, and the second problem, do not really understand, but i suppouse is a protection system.